# MySQL and/or query for advanced search between several tables

Tags: mysql

Now, I am using this query

```
    SELECT h . * , 

    (SELECT state
      FROM house_name
      WHERE name = h.house_name
      AND purpose = h.purpose
      AND district_id = (
       SELECT id
       FROM district
       WHERE name = h.district )
       LIMIT 1
    ) AS hstate, 

    (SELECT name
     FROM district
     WHERE id = (
     SELECT district_id
     FROM house_name
     WHERE name = h.house_name
     LIMIT 1 )
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS origin_d, 

    (SELECT id
     FROM house_name
     WHERE name = h.house_name
     AND purpose = h.purpose
     AND district_id = (
     SELECT id
     FROM district
     WHERE name = h.district )
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS hnameid, 

    m.display_name
    FROM house_detail h
    LEFT JOIN members m ON m.id = h.member_id
    WHERE 

    h.deleted =0
    AND h.approve =0
    AND 
    (SELECT state
    FROM house_name
    WHERE state = 'N'
    AND name = h.house_name
    AND purpose = h.purpose
    AND district_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM district
    WHERE 
    name = h.district )
    LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL
    AND h.price <=1000000
    OR h.price >=70000000
    OR (
    h.purpose = 'house'
    AND h.rent >=100000
    )
    OR (
    h.purpose = 'industry'
    AND h.rent >=700000
    )
    OR h.rent <=5000
```

On the Where clause:

1. The h.approve can be 0 or 1 or 2
2. The h.deleted can be 0 or 1
3. The state can be Y or N

What I want to do is:

1. The `h.deleted` , `h.approve` and the `state` MUST be  `0`, `0` and `N` respectively
2. The `h.rent` and `h.price` may under a specific range.

And the current problem is it will still select some data where the `h.deleted` , `h.approve` and `state` may be `1 or 2` , `1` and `Y`. I think it's because there're some `OR` between them.

Is there any way to output my expected result ?

Comment: Put the OR'd conditions inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Set bracket around the following statements:

```
WHERE 
name = h.district )
LIMIT 1
) IS NOT NULL
AND (h.price <=1000000
OR h.price >=70000000
OR (
h.purpose = 'house'
AND h.rent >=100000
)
OR (
h.purpose = 'industry'
AND h.rent >=700000
)
OR h.rent <=5000)
```

opening `(` after the last `AND` and closing `)` at the end... that should do